# How to change charger LED color on MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

I have the MacBook Air, and on the charger, there is a LED that is red-orange when charging, and green when charged. Is there any way to change the color of that? To, for instance, make it red when battery power is from 0-25, dark orange when the battery is 25-50, etc.?

Comment: Although the LED source does appear to be RGB I'm guessing that it has zero programmability.  It's likely chip (or IC) driven, to change it you would need source code for the IC and a method to load new software onto the chip.  The color scheme used here is popular in chargers, the same chips probably used in all, and it's probably also the voltage regulator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it could be possible to "change the color" of charger plug led easily without destroying it. It's hardwired. If you are good enough to work with soldering iron under microscope you could.

Here is a teardown: http://www.cqdx.ru/ham/do-it-yourself/diy-repair-the-mac-book-pro-l-type-power-supply-plug/

Comment: Actually the fact that the LED changes color in the first place indicates that the LED in use is already an RGB LED, meaning it already has capability of producing millions of different colors from a hardware standpoint.   The question is asking if there is anyway to change what color is used when progmatically.

Comment: Yes, of course that LED is possibly RGB. But you have to reprogram the microcontroller. How you going to reflash it? IMHO it needs much effort and reverse engineering than replacing it with some other micro controller with similar size. Again you have to work with microscope. If you already can work under microscope in such small scale, I have nothing to say. 

Try search for teardown or repair photos of plug. Then you can imagine how to modify the plug.

Maybe Tyson has right. It can also be a special chip used for PSUs.

Comment: See my comment on the question